# Ubuntu 16.04 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service 100% CPU consumption

Tags: cpu-load, gnome-software

From time to time process `/usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service` starts consuming 100% of one of my cores. It is fixed if I reboot, or kill it with `kill`.

Is there a way to understand why this is happening? I want to create bug report. I could not find anything related in `/var/log/`.

Comment: Did you find the answer for this?

Comment: Somewhy problem disappeared after I posted this. I didn't notice any strange cpu usage since I wrote this question.

Comment: Ha, i'm struggling with the same problem now. Eats all my CPU!

Comment: I'm not sure, but this could fixed by updates. I didn't have this problem for pretty much time.

Comment: about the software center:
If it is too power consuming you can always uninstall it by using sudo apt-get remove gnome-software

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/789385/software-and-updater-consumes-100-cpu-in-ubuntu-16-04/809810#809810 This link helped me to fix the same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Software and Updater consumes 100% CPU in Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/789385/software-and-updater-consumes-100-cpu-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and running `journalctl -f` to access the system logs explained it all: `org.gnome.Software` was running in loop because of a "corrupted package cache file", inviting me to run `apt-get update` to solve the issue

The logs (in French, sorry):

```
org.gnome.Software[2565]: E: Le fichier de cache des paquets est corrompu
org.gnome.Software[2565]: (gnome-software:3153): Gs-WARNING **: failed to call gs_plugin_refine_app on apt: apt DB load failed: error while initialising
org.gnome.Software[2565]: E: Impossible de traiter le fichier /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_atom_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-all_Packages (1)
```

I just killed the process and moved on, running apt-get commands doesn't produce any error and I'm not using gnome software center anyway. I would like to find a way to fully disable it though

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look into the file /var/log/kern.log its about the internals.

I have had one VM log some errors there, I snapshotted my VM and redeployed it the errors never happened again.

You may have a faulty core or overheating CPU, just my best guess.

Answer (score -3):

Among all the desktop environments, gnome is one of the most cpu power consuming desktop environment. Try removing the unnecessary daemons of gnome from `/etc/init` and restart you device. If this does not show any improvement then try switching to other desktop environments like XFCE or KDE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I mentioned in comments above this problem does not trouble me anymore. Most likely, it was fixed by updates.

Comment: Is this an answer? For me it is a vague advice.  No advice about `gnome-software --gapplication-service`.