# Software and Updater consumes 100% CPU in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, updates, software-center, cpu, cpu-load

I've upgraded my laptop (Lenovo Z50-70) which has an i7 CPU and 8Gigs of Ram to Ubuntu 16.04 from 15.10. I've been installing updates consistently. I'm using ubuntu with Gnome desktop environment (GDM).

Lately I've been experiencing a weird problem, my CPU (including all 4 cores) are 100% used by some processes like `gnome-software`(Gnome software) and `fwupd`(Firmware update daemon). This makes my work goes down. If i even kill those processes, they are starting back again.

Is there a solution for these processes to not utilize 100% of my CPU. And I don't want answers saying use the `cpulimit` utility to provision the amount of CPU for those processes. I find this a core problem in Ubuntu, i'm expecting real solutions for the problem.

*What I've tried so far is,*
Removing those PPA's i've added except the official PPA's for checking updates. That didn't work out!
Attached a screenshot of `htop` screen of these processes.

[image: Cpu 100% usage of gnome-software and fwupd]

Comment: Should probably file a bug report.

Comment: @mikewhatever I'm hoping i could get some hints or tips from the askubuntu community, if not I'm going to file a bug report or probably try some alternatives.

Comment: Have you checked for errors in `dmesg` or system logs in /var/log?

Comment: @Dorian `(Nothing has been logged yet.)` Says the `dmesg` file.

Comment: `dmesg` is a command you type that will output a log.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I did that and used grep with pipe to filter out any results for `gnome-software` or `fwupd`, nothing there. I explicitly tried /var/log/syslog as well.

Comment: You should also check `/var/log/apt/history.log` as well as other log files in that directory such as `/var/log/apt/term.log` or `/var/log/dpkg.log` which are all places to look for clues and errors.

Comment: @kisanme Any progress with this? I'm having the exact same problem - `fwupd` and `gnome-software` each at 100%. I'm also on 16.04.

Comment: @ChadScherrer I've found that my hardware is highly not supported for Ubuntu, but it seems to work fine with Linux Mint based on benchmarks and my personal experience for around a month now. So I moved into Linux mint from Ubuntu. Try checking your hardware compatibility with Ubuntu. Cheers

Comment: There is a bug posted which may be related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fwupd/+bug/1591868

Answer (score 23):

Had a similar issue.

As the other answer mentioned - it is possible to determine the problem by looking at `/var/log/syslog`.

Within my log gnome-settings was reporting the following:

```
(gnome-settings-daemon:3584): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/home/USER/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied.
```

In order to fix this I ran the following command, replace USER with your username:

```
sudo chown USER /home/USER/.cache/dconf
```

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same issue, same processes taking 100% of CPU. What worked for me was to upgrade software in my Ubuntu (16.04):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After that I **rebooted** my pc and now the issue is gone.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve it by checking syslog (`/var/log/syslog`). It was logging like crazy that it couldn't create the file `/home/<my user>/.cache/dconf/user`. When I gave this folder the correct permissions, it stopped using this much CPU.

Comment: «the correct permissions» It would be a good idea to include which permissions you gave and the command you issued to assign them.

Comment: That folder does not even exist on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Permission Problem for me.

looking at:

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog
```

> (gnome-software:3812): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file
>   '/home/{user}/.cache/dconf/user': Permiso denegado.  dconf will not
>   work properly.

Executing this command, the problem solved.

```
$ sudo chown {user} /home/{user}/.cache/dconf
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be a case when there's nothing in the syslog related to the service, in which case you may want to simply restart it. To avoid looking up services and killing them manually, you can just use `systemctl`:

```
sudo systemctl restart fwupd
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I didn't have the `/home/[user]/.cache` folder issues listed above.

Answer (score 1):

This problem with `fwupd` happened to me today on one computer. I also had two instances of `gnome-software` running. In all, 2 CPU were clamped at 100%.

To quickly stop that mayhem, I could just kill those 3 processes:

```
ps -ef | less
(find processes in the list, record their PID)

kill <pid1>
kill <pid2>
kill <pid3>
...
```

(You may also try `killall gnome-software` and `killall fwupd`, I just find that `killall` command dangerous... Otherwise, in `htop` you can just use F9. Before confirming, make sure the correct process was selected!)

Now, [@belacqua](https://askubuntu.com/users/8844/belacqua) pointed us out to the following bug report on launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream-glib/+bug/1591868

I found comment 18 particularly interesting:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream-glib/+bug/1591868/comments/18

The person says that the problem is not reproducible, but if you had problems with apt-get (as in, software update / installation) then it may very well be because of that. And indeed, I had several files in the apt cache that were total crap (i.e. my Internet connection failed a couple of days ago and some of the cache files included an HTTP 302 error instead of the expected package lists.) I find this specific comment interesting because a bug is still there, but not due to the yaml file as specified there. In my case, I could not find any yaml file anywhere.

I'd bet that by [fixing the `apt-get` cache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789103/ubuntu-suddenly-broke-audio-apt-get-and-flash#answer-843180), I fixed the problem. It looks like the code was fixed a while back already. I just need a reboot to confirm that this 100% CPU usage does not occur again.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with me, it also blocking my system.

After change owner of `/home/{user}/.cache/dconf/user`, it looks normal.