# fwupd taking up to 200% CPU

Tags: updates, 16.04, firmware

I ran recently `top` and see that `fwupd` is taking more than 200% CPU whole the time. Can any one say what this firmware update is and what should i do to make him leave the CPU? I am on 16.04.

Comment: Another complaint about `fwupd` hogging CPU is here: http://askubuntu.com/q/789385/248158

Comment: This is likely a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fwupd/+bug/1591868