# fwupd and gnome-software use 100% of my cpu

Tags: gnome, cpu, gnome-software

I've been installing Ubuntu 16.04 on my Asus X540LC Laptop which has an i5 cpu and 8gb ram. When I start working with Ubuntu everything is ok. But after a few weeks when I login into Ubuntu, something uses my cpu. I run the `top` command in the terminal and get this

[top command line tool on my ubuntu ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDQ8M.jpg)

When I see this, I try to kill this process manually and everything is ok after that. But I've searched about this problem and read this 
[Software and Updater consumes 100% CPU in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789385/software-and-updater-consumes-100-cpu-in-ubuntu-16-04)
but solutions on that post can't help me. And there is nothing that looks like that.

And there is something else. When I open Ubuntu software, this process comes back again. Can anyone help me to figure out why this happened?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I came here with that query