# Problems with input language switcher

Tags: language-support, input-language

Ubuntu 16.04 input language switching stop working after couple switches (two, three times) I've tried reinstalling language-support,tried reinstall ibus, maybe there is a way i can reinstall language-switcher ?

Comment: i have two languages for input,  and super+space shortcut for changing them, when i switch first time (using shortcut) from english to russian it works second time from russian to english works, but on third time it doesn't. After switching manually using language switcher menu in right top corner it works for next two three times.

Comment: I see, so it's input language you are talking about - since you mentioned `language-support` I thought it was the display language. I edited your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I runned `htop` and found that gnome-settings-daemon uses 99% CPU. Than i found this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/809810/640672 and it helped.